# Prometheus - JMX: Why doesn't Prometheus pull information via JMX port instead of requiring installation of a Jar on the target system?

Tags: prometheus, jmx

I am new to Prometheus. I was looking at ways to monitor Application Servers that don't ship with Prometheus support but do come with JMX.

Such applications provide some configuration to enable connections via the JMX port.

Why then does Prometheus require one to put Prometheus specific jars on the target system (The java-agent stuff)?  It could just connect to the JMX port and pull whatever information it needs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prometheus doesn't aim to support every possible application out there in one binary - there's just too many. Instead the ~500ish exporters exist to act as translators, and Prometheus can focus on what it does best.

Comment: Those translators don't need to run on the target systems. They can live on the same machine as Prometheus and access JMX data over the network (or they could live alongside the app but still connect to JMX via a local socket connection). Attaching a java agent is pretty invasive. Many complex softwares startup with a vendor provided script. Attaching a java agent there would mean modifying those scripts. Whereas use of JMX by user is something the vendor has planned for - it is well documented.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer on the JMX Exporter's Github page:

> This exporter is intended to be run as a Java Agent, exposing a HTTP
>   server and serving metrics of the local JVM. **It can be also run as an
>   independent HTTP server and scrape remote JMX targets, but this has
>   various disadvantages, such as being harder to configure and being
>   unable to expose process metrics (e.g., memory and CPU usage)**. Running
>   the exporter as a Java Agent is thus strongly encouraged.